# Inconsistent errors using limit and since with Facebook Graph API v2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to grab event information from the Greek Theatre in LA, this query works for me:

```
47761106438/events?fields=id,name,start_time,end_time,owner,admins{id,name},place&limit=100
```

But I find it quite off that using a limit of 10 returns no results!

```
47761106438/events?fields=id,name,start_time,end_time,owner,admins{id,name},place&limit=10
```

Then I can use the "since" parameter as well. I can query since the beginning of time which works:

```
47761106438/events?fields=id,name,start_time,end_time,owner,admins{id,name},place&limit=100&since=0
```

but it would be nice to query the future (thats a unix timestamp for right now):

```
47761106438/events?fields=id,name,start_time,end_time,owner,admins{id,name},place&limit=100&since=1438758276
```

however, I get an "unsupported request" error which is lame. But I noticed that if I try this same exact query from another node, such as Techcrunch, then it works!

```
8062627951/events?fields=id,name,start_time,end_time,owner,admins{id,name},place&limit=100&since=1438758276
```

And after a ridiculous amount of tinkering around, I was able to determine that the Greek Theatre query works if I leave out the "admins" field:

```
47761106438/events?fields=id,name,start_time,end_time,owner,place&limit=100&since=1438758276
```

Now I couldn't imagine Facebook would create such an inconsistent API, but I have no idea what's going on here!

Comment: That sounds like a bug and should be reported at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs if there isn't a report for this already

Comment: ok. thanks. I submitted a bug